# Unable to add folder to PATH in .profile file

Tags: environment-variables, path, profile

The following is my `.profile` file:

```
# ~/.profile: executed by the command interpreter for login shells.
# This file is not read by bash(1), if ~/.bash_profile or ~/.bash_login
# exists.
# see /usr/share/doc/bash/examples/startup-files for examples.
# the files are located in the bash-doc package.

# the default umask is set in /etc/profile; for setting the umask
# for ssh logins, install and configure the libpam-umask package.
#umask 022

# if running bash
if [ -n "$BASH_VERSION" ]; then
    # include .bashrc if it exists
    if [ -f "$HOME/.bashrc" ]; then
    . "$HOME/.bashrc"
    fi
fi

# set PATH so it includes user's private bin if it exists
if [ -d "$HOME/bin" ] ; then
    PATH="$HOME/bin:$PATH"
    export PATH=/home/naveen/bin:~/../../usr/local/MATLAB/R2015a/bin/:$PATH
fi
```

The path to `matlab` (`~/../../usr/local/MATLAB/R2015a/bin/`) was recently added. But, after adding the `matlab` path, I am still NOT able to run `matlab` from ANY folder by simply running the command `./matlab`.

I am adding the path correctly ?

Should I reboot the system for the changes to apply ?

Comment: It seems that you have three problems here: 1) Do not use `~` to refer to your `$HOME`; 2) Do not forget to do `source ~/.profile` to activate the script (it won't be necessary afterward) 3) Do not call `./matlab` but `matlab`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A reboot isn't necessary, but reloading your `.profile` is. Try running `source .profile`. Alternatively, you can log off and log on again.

Comment: Ah, I forgot this also... Combine the two answers...

Comment: The changed suggested by @Gilles followed by reloading did the trick. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

The main problem is that `./matlab` runs the executable called `matlab` in the current directory. To look for it in `$PATH`, you need to **type just `matlab`**. The `PATH` variable is only used when there's no slash in the command name.

Also, remove the `export PATH=…` line and instead add

```
PATH=$PATH:/usr/local/MATLAB/R2015a/bin
```

or

```
PATH=/usr/local/MATLAB/R2015a/bin:$PATH
```

before the `if [ -d "$HOME/bin" ]` line. There's already code to add `/home/naveen/bin` (assuming that's your home directory, and if not `$HOME/bin` is the correct one to add), so you don't need to add it again. If `$HOME/bin` doesn't exist, you still want to add the Matlab directory, so it belongs outside the `if`. Use an absolute path, a relative path makes no sense here. Add the Matlab directory either first or last depending on whether you want Matlab executables to have priority over other executables by the same name in different directories (there are probably no executables by the same name, in which case it doesn't matter).

You don't need to reboot. However, `.profile` is only read when you log in. You can also reload it for a terminal session by typing `. ~/.profile` in the shell; this only applies to programs started from that particular shell.

Answer (score 2):

Your example wouldn't do anything if `$HOME/bin` doesn't exist. Maybe try this instead:

```
# set PATH so it includes user's private bin if it exists
if [ -d "$HOME/bin" ] ; then
    PATH="$HOME/bin:$PATH"
fi
PATH=/usr/local/MATLAB/R2015a/bin/:$PATH
```

And, running `./matlab` will never work (if `matlab` is not in the current directory) because you are trying to run `matlab` specifically in the current directory. Simply run `matlab`.

Another option would be to symlink matlab into your `$HOME/bin` instead of adding it to the path (if it is the only executable you want to run from there:)

```
ln -s /usr/local/MATLAB/R2015a/bin/matlab ~/bin/
```

Edit: And you'll need to logout or run `source ~/.profile` in every shell.

Answer (score 1):

Try to type simply `matlab` and not `./matlab`.

The `./` means that you are looking for the executable `matlab` in the current directory without going through the `PATH` variable.

Comment: Yes. Tried that. I get a 'matlab: command not found' error.